# Convenient way to find the declaration of a variable

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis

Sometimes I am reading some code and would like to find the definition for a certain symbol, but it is sprinkled throughout the code to such an extent that `grep` is more or less insufficient for pointing me to its definition.

For example, I am working with Zlib and I want to figure out what `FAR` means.

```
Steven@Steven-PC /c/Users/Steven/Desktop/zlib-1.2.5
$ grep "FAR" * -R | wc -l
260
```

That's a lot to scan through. It turns out it is in fact `#define`d to nothing but it took me some time to figure it out.

If I was using Eclipse I would have it easy because I can just hover over the symbol and it will tell me what it is.

What kinds of tools out there can I use to analyze code in this way? Can GCC do this for me? `clang` maybe? I'm looking for something command-line preferably. Some kind of tool that isn't a full fledged IDE at any rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/), it's basically made for this, and a command line tool (if you like, using ncurses). Also, libclang (part of clang/llvm) can do so - but that's just a library (but took me just ~100 lines of python to use libclang to emulate basic cscope features).

cscope requires you to build a database first. libclang can parse code "live".

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is not declared in your curernt file, it is declared in an included file, i.e. a `.h`. So you can limit the amount of data by performing a grep only on those files.

Moreover, you can filter whole word matches with `-w` option of grep.

Try:

```
grep -w "FAR" *.h -R | wc -l
```

Comment: the symbol may also be declared for the first time in a file included in the included .h file, and so on... so your method sometimes fails.

Answer (score 1):

Our [Source Code Search Engine (SCSE)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) is kind of graphical grep that indexes a large code base according to the tokens of its language(s) (e.g., C, Java, COBOL, ...).  Queries are stated in terms of the tokens, not strings, so finding an identifier won't find it in the middle of a comment.  This minimizes false positives, and in a big code base these can be a serious waste of time.   Found hits are displayed one per line; a click takes to the source text.
One can do queries from the command line and get grep-like responses, too.

A query of the form of

```
 I=foo*
```

will find all uses of any identifier that starts with the letters "foo".

Queries can compose mulitiple tokens:

```
 I=foo* '[' ... ']' '='
```

finds assignments to a subscripted foo ("..." means "near").

For C, Java and COBOL, the SCSE can find reads, writes, updates, and declarations of variables.

```
D=*baz
```

finds declarations of variables whose names end in "baz".  I think this is what OP is looking for.

While SCSE works for C++, it presently can't find reads/writes/updates/declarations in C++. It does everything else.

The SCSE will handle mixed languages with aplomb.  An "I" query will search across all langauges that have identifiers, so you can see cross language calls relatively easily, since the source and target identifiers tend to be the same for software engineering reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` can output the pre-processing result, with all macro definitions with `gcc -E -dD`. The output file would be rather larger, often due to the nested system headers. But the first appearance of a symbol is usually the declaration (definition). The output use `#line` to show the part pre-processed result belong to source/header file, so you can find where it is originally declared.

To get the exact result when the file is compiled, you may need to add all other parameters used to compile the file, like `-I`, `-D`, etc. In fact, I always copy a result compilation command line, and add `-E -dD` to the beginning, and add (or change) `-o` in case I accidental overwrite anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is [gccxml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html), but I am not aware of tools that build on top of it. clang and [LLVM](http://llvm.org) are suited for such stuff, too; equally, I am not aware of standalone tools that build on them.

Apart from that: QtCreator and code::blocks can find the declartion, too.

Answer (score 0):

So what is it about a "full fledged IDE" you don't want?  If its a little speed, I found netbeans somewhat usefull when I was in school, but really for power and speed and general utility I would like to reccomend emacs.  It has key board shortcuts for things like this.  Keep in mind, its a learning curve to be sure, but once you are over the hump there is no going back.

Comment: Does emacs actually process the language to determine where a symbol is declared, for instance?

Comment: Here are some links that may help you with what emacs is capable of: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790065/emacs-is-there-a-semantic-jump-to-declaration-using-semantic-el), [link](http://deep.syminet.com/emacside.html)